# how to pull @ mentions out of strings like twitter in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, twitter

I am writing an application in Node.js that allows users to mention each other in messages like on twitter. I want to be able to find the user and send them a notification. In order to do this I need to pull @usernames to find mentions from a string in node.js?

Any advice, regex, problems?

Comment: I think this one is different because it is specific to a language. I think it is great for people to reference that article but it is not updated with the best answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I have found that this is the best way to find mentions inside of a string in javascript.

```
var str = "@jpotts18 what is up man? Are you hanging out with @kyle_clegg";
var pattern = /\B@[a-z0-9_-]+/gi;
str.match(pattern);
["@jpotts18", "@kyle_clegg"]
```

I have purposefully restricted it to upper and lowercase alpha numeric and (-,_) symbols in order to avoid periods that could be confused for usernames like (@j.potts).

This is what [twitter-text.js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/twitter-text.js#L91) is doing behind the scenes.

```
// Mention related regex collection
twttr.txt.regexen.validMentionPrecedingChars = /(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&*@＠]|RT:?)/;
twttr.txt.regexen.atSigns = /[@＠]/;
twttr.txt.regexen.validMentionOrList = regexSupplant(
    '(#{validMentionPrecedingChars})' +  // $1: Preceding character
    '(#{atSigns})' +                     // $2: At mark
    '([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})' +             // $3: Screen name
    '(\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{0,24})?'  // $4: List (optional)
  , 'g');
twttr.txt.regexen.endMentionMatch = regexSupplant(/^(?:#{atSigns}|[#{latinAccentChars}]|:\/\/)/);
```

Please let me know if you have used anything that is more efficient, or accurate. Thanks!

Comment: This will match a single `@` as well. To prevent that you can replace the `*` with a `+`

Comment: yoo could also add a word delimiter before the '@' to make sure you dont accidentally trap emails: var str = "@jpotts18 what is up man? Are you hanging out with @kyle_clegg, contact me at foo@bar.com"; str.match(/\B@[a-z0-9_-]+/gi);

Comment: Great comment Timothee! That is great advice to keep in mind. I will update my regex based on your suggestion @TimothéeGroleau

Comment: GREATE BOY! :D Tnks for tip very very helpfull!

Comment: Hi, this pattern split dot character "@this.is.me" only detected become "@this"

Comment: Just needed this function myself for a project, so put it into a Clay function, if you want to try out the regex, or use it as an API: 
https://www.clay.run/services/nicoslepicos/parse-at-usernames-in-string

Hope it's useful & thanks for sharing the code!

Comment: Definitely use twitter-text.js. The simplistic regex provided above is just wrong on so many counts, just a few examples: (1) hyphens aren't valid in username, (2) it fails to match a mention at the beginning of a string, (3) it doesn't match "ä@username" whereas twitter considers this a mention, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Twitter has a library that you should be able to use for this. https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js.

I haven't used it, but if you trust its description, "the library provides autolinking and extraction for URLs, usernames, lists, and hashtags.". You should be able to use it in Node with `npm install twitter-text`.

While I understand that you're not looking for Twitter usernames, the same logic still applies and you should be able to use it fine (it does not validate that extracted usernames are valid twitter usernames). If not, forking it for your own purposes may be a very good place to start.

Edit: I looked at the docs closer, and there is a perfect example of what you need right [here](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js#extraction-examples).

```
var usernames = twttr.txt.extractMentions("Mentioning @twitter and @jack")
// usernames == ["twitter", "jack"]
```

Comment: Thanks nick. I have edited my answer to pull in the regex from that library. I had no idea there are 2 @ symbols. huh...

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept if you feel its the correct answer. And ya things like that happen, which is why I always opt to use a maintained library for things like this rather than writing it myself. It may seem easy enough, but the small things that (virtually) no one know about lead to horridly hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you extract mentions from instagram caption with JavaScript and underscore.

```
var _ = require('underscore');

function parseMentions(text) {
    var mentionsRegex = new RegExp('@([a-zA-Z0-9\_\.]+)', 'gim');

    var matches = text.match(mentionsRegex);
    if (matches && matches.length) {
        matches = matches.map(function(match) {
            return match.slice(1);
        });
        return _.uniq(matches);
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would respect names with diacritics, or character from any language `\p{L}`.

```js
/(?<=^| )@\p{L}+/gu
```

[Example on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TY4DM3/2) with description.

PS:
[Don't use `\B`](https://regex101.com/r/qUaT5j/1) since it will match `@@wrong`.