# String Matching Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js, string

I want to get the characters after @ symbol till a space character.

for eg. if my string is like   `hello @world. some gibberish.@stackoverflow`. Then I want to get the characters 'world' and 'stackoverflow'.

Here is what I have been trying.

```
var comment = 'hello @world. some gibberish.@stackoverflow';
 var indices = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
        if (comment[i] === "@") {
            indices.push(i);
            for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++){
               startIndex.push(comment[j]); 
            }
        }
    }
```

I can get the occurences of @ and spaces and then trim that part to get my content but I'd like a better solution / suggestion for this, with without REGEX. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want a solution without regex? This is exactly what regex was made to do.

Comment: `str.split('@').splice(1).map(function(w) { return w.split(' ')[0];  })`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265605/how-to-pull-mentions-out-of-strings-like-twitter-in-javascript, https://www.npmjs.com/package/mentions-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/@(\S+)/g
```

and grab captured groups using `exec` method in a loop.

This regex matches `@` and then `\S+` matches 1 or more non-space characters that are grouped in a captured group.

**Code:**

```js
var re = /@(\S+)/g; 
var str = 'hello @world. some gibberish.@stackoverflow';
var m;
var matches=[];

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}

document.writeln("<pre>" + matches + "</pre>");
```

PS: Note you will need to use

```
/@([^.\s]+)/g
```

if you don't want to capture DOT after `word`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly fine. Also any good reference if you can recommend with plenty of examples for learning regex? Thanks in advance!