# How to fix {user.username} when user isn't a string?

Tags: discord.js

I'm actually coding a Js Discord Bot, and I am creating an XP system.

I want my bot give the level of the author when `&level` is entered, and it works.

But if i do `&level @DiscordUser`, i can get the user id of this Discord User except when i use it in a embed like this :

```js
const embed = {
                  "title": "Fiche Niveau d'Exagide",
                  "description": 'Utilisateur : **' + `${userid.username}` + "**",
                  "color": 10384204
               }
```

In this case it returns : `Utilisateur : undefined`

`userid` is a const get from a function who transform a Mention to an ID

For eg it turns `<@549317568339640336>` to `549317568339640336`

```js
function getUserFromMention(mention) {
              if (!mention) return;

              if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
                mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

                if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
                  mention = mention.slice(1);
                }
                return mention;
              }}
```

I just expect that the embed return `Utilisateur : Discord User` if `@Discord User` was mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply use the following to get the user Object of the mentioned user:

```
message.mentions.users.first()
```

or the member Object of the mentionned user:

```
message.mentions.members.first()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code

```
 function mentionsRegex (dot) {
if (dot) {
// e.g. @google.com will match `google.com`
return /(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_＠!@#$%&*])(?:(?:@|＠)(?!\/))([a-zA-Z0-9/_.]{1,15}) 
 (?:\b(?!@|＠)|$)/
}
 // e.g. @google.com will match `google`
return /(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_＠!@#$%&*])(?:(?:@|＠)(?!\/))([a-zA-Z0-9/_]{1,15})(?:\b(?!@| 
＠)|$)/
}
```

taken from [mentions-regex](https://github.com/regexhq/mentions-regex/blob/master/index.js)
also you can see [mentions out of strings like twitter in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265605/how-to-pull-mentions-out-of-strings-like-twitter-in-javascript)

Comment: It is not working it return this /(?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_＠!@#$%&*])(?:(?:@|＠)(?!\/))([a-zA-Z0-9/_]{1,15})(?:\b(?!@| 
＠)|$)/ and not the User ID