# check every occurrence of a special character followed by a whitespace using regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check for every occurrence that a string has an `@` at the beginning of a string.

So something like this works for only one string occurance

```
const comment = "@barnowl is cool"
const regex = /@[a-z]/i;

if (comment.charAt(0).includes("@")) {
  if (regex.test(comment)) {
     // do something 
    console.log('test passeed')
  } else {
      // do something else
  }
} else {
      // do other 
}
```

but....

What if you have a textarea and a user uses the `@`  multiple times to reference another user this test will no longer work because charAt(0) is looking for the first character in a string.

What regex test is doable in a situation where you have to check the occurrence of a `@` followed by a space. I know i can ditch `charAt(0)` and use `comment.includes("@")` but i want to use a regex pattern to check if there is space after wards

So if user does @username followed by a space after words, the regex should pass.

Doing this `\s` doesn't seem to make the test pass

```
const regex = /@[a-z]\s/i; // shouldn't this check for white space after a letter ?
```

demo:

https://jsbin.com/riraluxape/edit?js,console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265605/how-to-pull-mentions-out-of-strings-like-twitter-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expression is very close. There are two things that are missing:

- The `[a-z]` match is only looking for one character, so in order to look for multiple characters it needs to be `[a-z]+`.
- The flags section is missing the `g` modifier, which enables the expression to look through the entire text string instead of just the first match.

I believe the regular expression declaration should be adjusted to the following:

```js
const regex = /@[a-z]+\s/ig;
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for multiple matches instead of only the first one, append `g` to the regex:

```
const regex = /@[a-z]*\s/ig;
```

Your regex with `\s` actually works, see: https://regex101.com/r/gyMyvB/1

Comment: I want to stick with the `\s` approach and its not working on my demo, would you have an idea ?

Comment: `const regex = /@[a-z]*\s/ig;` is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Matching all the occurrences of the mention?

```js
const regex = /@\w+/ig
```

I used the `\w` flag here which matches any word character.

Comment: This is a great way of potentially simplifying the expression. One thing to note is that `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which may include more characters than intended.